# Deploy nodejs application to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I have a clone of the repository https://github.com/ibnclaudius/express-mongoose-es6-rest-api, I want to deploy to Heroku. In the deployments instructions are written as follows:

```
# compile to ES5
1. npm run build or gulp

# upload dist/ to your server
2. scp -rp dist/ user@dest:/path

# install production dependencies only
3. npm i --production

# Use any process manager to start your services
4. pm2 start dist/index.js
```

> In production you need to make sure your server is always up so you
>   should ideally use any of the process manager recommended here. We
>   recommend pm2 as it has several useful features like it can be
>   configured to auto-start your services if system is rebooted.

I'm not sure how to proceed. How can I deploy as recommended but in the context of Heroku? I tried to send through the Heroku CLI but did not succeed.

What I tried:

```
npm run build
cd dist/
git init
heroku git:remote -a farm-rooster
git add .
git commit -am "Início"
git push heroku master
```

The application log:

> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.364424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get
>   information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.364648+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't
>   available, you can get their info via:
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.364968+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>   express-mongoose-es6-rest-api
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.365079+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.368518+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.368965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include
>   the following file with any support request:
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.369132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>   /app/npm-debug.log
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.469487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
>   starting to crashed
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:33.457348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
>   status 1
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:35.414253+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=farm-rooster.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=e88f1c0e-4ea5-4610-82d6-b437bf37ea0e fwd="186.203.235.191"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-10-09T23:33:36.117238+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
>   desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
>   host=farm-rooster.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=c8859482-b508-4e93-b9dc-3455558d13ed fwd="186.203.235.191"
>   dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Are you using heroku's free or paid plans?

Comment: Free, but what is the difference?

Comment: Free dynos sleep after 30mins but I realized this is insignificant in your case

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you get when deploying using the CLI?

Comment: I'm currently developing the application, so I'm in the free plan. When deploy into production will change to a paid plan. I'll update my question. But I have no idea on how to implement the pm2 process manager.

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn Which port are you using? You should be setting your port like so `app.set("port", (process.env.PORT));`

Comment: I'm using 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - You could try adding a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-naming-and-location) to the project before sending it to Heroku. I think it should be like `web: npm run start`.

2 - You shouldn't send just the dist folder to Heroku, you should send the whole project. Heroku will build it and then run (this is one of Heroku's features btw).

3 - PM2 is suggested so your application is monitored and restarted if it breaks. Heroku will do it for you so I don't think using PM2 here is really useful

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear regarding `Procfile` and handling `/dist` folder

Procfile,

> To determine how to start your app, Heroku first looks for a Procfile.
>   If no Procfile exists for a Node.js app, we will attempt to start a
>   default web process via the start script in your package.json. So you can either have Procfile or you can define Start section in your package.json. e.g. `"start": "node server.js"`

`/dist` folder

You have two options

1. Push `dist` folder to heroku along with other application stuff.
2. Don't push `dist` and keep it ignored in your gitignore file. Use `postintall script` in your package.json to create /dist folder `"postinstall": "ng build --prod"` [postinstall script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support)