# How can i deploy a Selenium NodeJS web app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I have created a Selenium `NodeJS` web app in Local. It uses `chromedriver` and my driver must use some chrome extensions. Everything is ok in local.
I want to use it in Heroku but I could not do it. I tried it with build packs but but I could not do it again.

How can i deploy it to Heroku ?

package.json (dependencies):

```
..
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "*",
    "express": "*",
    "firebase": "^4.1.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "*",
    "chromedriver":"*",
    "telebot":"*"
  },
..
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy nodejs application to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949489/deploy-nodejs-application-to-heroku)

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am using React, Express, and Selenium with chrome

Step 1: Create a new Heroku app.

Step 2: From your terminal, login to heroku using `heroku login`

step 3: Once you're logged in, `cd` to your project directory and set it's remote to your heroku app. `heroku git:remote -a YOUR-HEROKU-APP-NAME`

step 4: Run all the following commands in your terminal

```
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
heroku config:set CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
heroku config:set CHROME_BINARY_PATH=/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

step 5: Login to heroku from your browser and navigate to your app. Go to settings and under `buildpacks`, add `heroku/nodejs`

step 6: This is how my index.js looks like. Note: my express entry point is inside `root-dir/server/index.js` and my react files are inside `root-dir/client/`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// Serve static files from the React app. 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client/build')));


app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    require('chromedriver');
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.setChromeBinaryPath(process.env.CHROME_BINARY_PATH);
    let serviceBuilder = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(process.env.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
    
    //Don't forget to add these for heroku
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
  

    let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
        .build();

    await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    res.send(await driver.getTitle());
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port ${port} now...`);
});
```

step 7 (if you are using React): Now inside your `package.json` in `root-dir/`, add this

```
"scripts": {
...
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
}
```

step 8 (if you are using react): inside your `package.json` in `root-dir/client/` (i.e: `package.json` for react app), add the following line:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/",
```

step 8: (if you're using react): inside `root-dir/client/src/`, create a new file called `setupProxy.js` and paste the following code:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api', { target: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 5000}/`}));
};
```

step 9: Now, you are ready for deployment. Make sure you have the following packages installed: `express`, `selenium-webdriver`, and `chromedriver`

step 10: now push it to heroku

```
git add .
git commit -m "my app"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do the following steps to deploy your application on heroku

1)make an new repository on git
     create an account on github and create an new repository
     then on command line check the status of your project file using

```
git status
```

if they are red mark then add all the file using

```
git add .
```

then commit

```
git commit -m "first commit"
```

2)push all the data on that repository

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/git_account/repository_name.git
   git push -u origin master
```

3) then push from git to heroku

```
git push heroku
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I wonder how it works in ChromeDriver in Heroku. Sorry.